# Making compound words into plural

Tags: java

I have this program which can make some singular nouns plural (I know I'm missing a lot, but that's aside the point). When I enter in a word such as "man-of-war" it returns as "mans-of-war" instead of "men-of-war". How do I fix this? My code can already make man to men, just not in the case I mentioned. Also for this program every compound word will have the dash, it is simply for practice.

```
public class LanguageUtils {

static boolean checkException(String noun){ 
    String[] exceptions = {"fish", "fox", "deer", "moose", "sheep", "cattle","pants","scissors"};
    for(int i=0;i<exceptions.length;i++) {
        if(exceptions[i].equals(noun))
            return true;
    }  
    return false;       
}

static boolean EnglishConsonant(char ch) {
    switch (Character.toLowerCase(ch)) {
        case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
            return false;
        default:
            return true;
    }
}

static String makePlural (String noun){
    String pluralWord = "";
    int length = noun.length();
    String strippedWord = noun.substring(0, noun.length()-1);
    char lastLetter = noun.charAt(noun.length()-1);

    if(noun.contains("-")){
        String nounsaver = noun.substring(noun.indexOf('-'), noun.length());
        pluralWord = noun.substring(0,noun.indexOf('-')) + "s" + nounsaver;
    }
    else{
    switch (lastLetter){
        case 's':
        case 'x':
        case 'z':
            if(noun.equals("ox")){
                 pluralWord = noun + "en";
                 break;
            }
            else{
                pluralWord = noun + "es";
                break;
            }
        case 'o':
            if(EnglishConsonant(noun.charAt(noun.length()-2))){
                pluralWord = strippedWord + "oes";
                break;
            }
        case 'e':
            char f = noun.charAt(noun.length()-2);
            String prec = noun.substring(0, noun.length()-2);
            if(f == 'f'){
                pluralWord = prec + "ves";
                break;
            }
            if(noun.equals("goose")){
                pluralWord = "geese";
                break;
            }
            else{
                pluralWord = noun + "s";
                break;
            }
        case 'h': 
            if ((noun.charAt(noun.length()-2)== 'c') || (noun.charAt(noun.length()-2)== 's')) {
                pluralWord = noun + "es";
                break;
            }
        case 'f':
            if (EnglishConsonant(noun.charAt(noun.length()-2))) {
                pluralWord = strippedWord + "ves";
                break;
            }
        case 'y':
            if (EnglishConsonant(noun.charAt(noun.length()-2))) {
                pluralWord = strippedWord + "ies";
                break;
            }  
        default:    
            if(noun.equals("foot")){
                pluralWord = "feet";
                break;
            }
            if(noun.endsWith("man")){
                pluralWord = noun.substring(0, noun.length()-3)+"men";
                break;
            }
            else{
                pluralWord = noun + "s";
                break;
            }
    }
    }
    if (length == 1){
        pluralWord = noun + "'s";
    }
    if(checkException(noun)){
        pluralWord = noun;
    }
    return pluralWord;
}
```

}

Comment: see String.indexOf or Pattern & Matcher

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with a compound word, if you need to pluralize a part, call a function designed to do just that: `makePlural`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have - then break the words and call the makePlural for those words again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)):

```
if (noun.contains("man")) {
    pluralWord = noun.replace("man", "men");
    break;
}
```